# ngInclude not inserting properly fetched DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

**EDIT**: It was a short-lived bug with ng-include inside ng-repeat. I never updated my angular dependency. Solution Found here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/JjmnPQl-SWg

This is a very difficult problem, because I can't even replicate the issue on plunker because it works on plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/gORzr0HEK6ZU6JymH0Bb?p=preview

I'm creating a dashboard for my web application. Essentially, I have a number of nested directives each with a templateUrl. Within the 4th layer of directives, I have:

```
<div data-ng-include="widget.tpl"></div>
```

Everything seems to be in place perfectly. On Chrome, the network tab indicates the HTML file is returning with the correct result, inspecting the DOM shows the appropriate

```
<!-- ngInclude: widget.tpl -->
```

directly before where the template should be loaded. It's not a matter of some sort of race condition because the tpl url is hard-coded, not dynamically calculated in my link function. The AngularJS properties on the elements show the appropriate properties in their scopes for that directive.

Yet the ng-included template is not appended to the DOM.

Any help or guidance with this would be glorious. As you can see in the above plunker, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have just commented, but I don't have enough rep.  I think I'd consider starting to work upstream to your parent directives to see if anything above could be causing a problem.  Take away one level of complexity at a time until you find something that changes the behavior.  Does the Plunker code work if you use it locally?  Without seeing the broken code I think it will be hard for anyone to help.  Sorry if my answer isn't what you're looking for.